# Opencart Controller Data are not defined in View

Tags: php, opencart

I'm trying to integrate my opencart store with ContactPigeon. 
ContactPigeon needs the email of the customer if the customer is logged in.

Journal 3 is my current theme.

They suggest to add the code in footer before the `</body>` tag.

I went on `catalog/controller/common/footer.php` and I add the below code

```
$data['logged'] = $this->customer->isLogged();
$data['customer_email'] = $this->customer->getEmail();
```

… inside `index()` function.

Then I went to catalog/view/theme/journal3/template/common/footer.tpl and I add the below code:

```
if($logged){ console.log('logged in'); }else{ console.log('not logged') }
```

I got error in console saying

```
$logged is not defined
```

I have already tried to refresh Modifications but not worked.

Answer (score 0):

In Journal 3 .tpl and OC 2.x you should retrieve data something like this:
catalog/controller/common/footer.php

```
$data['logged'] = $this->customer->isLogged(); 
$data['customer_email'] = $this->customer->getEmail();
$data['logged_in'] = 'Logged In';
```

In journal 3 catalog/view/theme/journal3/template/common/footer.tpl

```
<?php if ($logged): ?>
<?php echo $logged_in; ?> 
<?php endif; ?>
```